# How To Migrate Spark Scala Azure Mounting Code into Pyspark Code

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, azure-databricks

I would like to migrate below spark scala code into databricks  pyspark supported to check if my container already exists in or else I have mount the container, which we planned to keep it centralized for all the team members to use this code. kindly help us.

```
principal
val configs = Map(
  "fs.azure.account.auth.type" -> "OAuth",
  "fs.azure.account.oauth.provider.type" -> "org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.oauth2.ClientCredsTokenProvider",
  "fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.id" -> dbutils.secrets.get(scope = "sample-scope", key = "sample--client-id"),
  "fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.secret" -> dbutils.secrets.get(scope = "sample-scope", key = "sample-client-secret"),
  "fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.endpoint" -> "https://login.microsoftonline.com/33333df5c2-953a-444444444/oauth2/token"
)

val adlsPath = "abfss://container@storageaccount.dfs.core.windows.net/"
val mountPoint = "/mnt/containername"

if (dbutils.fs.mounts.map(mnt => mnt.mountPoint).contains(mountPoint)) {
  println(mountPoint + " already mounted")
}
else {
  println(mountPoint + " not mounted, mounting now")
  try {
    dbutils.fs.mount(
      source = adlsPath,
      mountPoint = mountPoint,
      extraConfigs = configs)
  }
  catch {
    case e: java.rmi.RemoteException => {
      println("exception encountered while mounting " + adlsPath)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Python code below.

```py
# configs1 = {
#     "fs.azure.account.auth.type": "OAuth",
#     "fs.azure.account.oauth.provider.type": "org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.oauth2.ClientCredsTokenProvider",
#     "fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.id": dbutils.secrets.get(scope="sample-scope", key="sample-client-id"),
#     "fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.secret": dbutils.secrets.get(scope="sample-scope", key="sample-client-secret"),
#     "fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.endpoint": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/33333df5c2-953a-444444444/oauth2/token"
# }

configs2 = {
    "fs.azure.account.key.jadls2.blob.core.windows.net": "acc_key"
}

adls_path = "wasbs://data@jadls2.blob.core.windows.net/"
mount_point = "/mnt/jadls2"

if any(mount.mountPoint == mount_point for mount in dbutils.fs.mounts()):
    print(mount_point + " already mounted")
else:
    print(mount_point + " not mounted, mounting now")
    try:
        dbutils.fs.mount(
            source=adls_path,
            mount_point=mount_point,
            extra_configs=configs2
        )
    except Exception as e:
        if "RemoteException" in str(e):
            print("Exception encountered while mounting " + adls_path)
            
dbutils.fs.ls(mount_point)
```

Here, I tried with an account key, but that's not recommended; you should use a service principal.

Output:

[image]

Refer to this article for more information.

[Mount ADLS Gen2 or Blob Storage in Azure Databricks (microsoft.com)](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-paas-blog/mount-adls-gen2-or-blob-storage-in-azure-databricks/ba-p/3802926)